# Android sqlite3 says "no _id" but table definitely has

Tags: android, sqlite

Somehow while debugging a little Location based android app I get a strange exception. Have a look and share your ideas:

I have connected a `ListActivity` with an sqlite3 database through a `ContentProvider`. Now always when I start the `ListActivity` the program dies with an Exception telling me

```
column '_id' does not exist
```

(without a table name) for the line where I create the `SimpleCursorAdapter` object for my `ListActivity`.

```
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(intent.getData(), new String[] {TrackTable.START_LOC, TrackTable.END_LOC}, null, null,
            TrackTable.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.gps_track_entry, cursor, new String[] {
                    TrackTable.COLUMN_NAME_TIME_START,
                    TrackTable.COLUMN_NAME_TIME_END
                }, new int[] { R.id.l_start, R.id.l_end });
```

My database looks like that:

```
sqlite> .tables
.tables
android_metadata ocation track
sqlite> . schema track
.schema track
CREATE TABLE track (
  _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  start_location INTEGER,
  end_location INTEGER,
  start_time TEXT,
  end_time TEXT
);
sqlite> .schema location
.schema location
CREATE TABLE location (
  _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  long TEXT,
  lat TEXT,
  alt TEXT,
  accu TEXT,
  bear TEXT,
  sped TEXT,
  time TEXT);
sqlite> .schema android_metadata
.schema android_metadata
CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT);
```

I mean, it is quite unlikely that the mistake is an Android bug, but it definitely looks like one, because the only table without an _id is the `android_metadata`. But maybe I wrote something in a strange way, that the VM now thinks I want to use `android_metadata` and not `track`, which I actually want to use.

Comment: Could you show the code used to create the cursor?  The _id field has to be part of the cursors result set.

Comment: Try setting it to autoincrement - create table track (_id integer primary key autoincrement, ........)

Comment: @Erich Douglass: Don't know why you didn't write that as an answer. That absolutely was the problem.

Comment: I need the points more than Erich :)

Comment: @erikb I'm just happy you got your issue solved :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Erich is right above; the problem is that your SELECT query needs to include BaseColumns._ID as part of the projection. Something like:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(TrackTable.CONTENT_URI, 
        new String[] { TrackTable._ID, TrackTable.COLUMN_NAME_TIME_START,
        TrackTable.COLUMN_NAME_TIME_END }, null, null, null);
```

BTW, see the javadoc for [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html%3a):

> The Cursor must include a column named "_id" or this class will not work.

Comment: Absolutely, that was the problem! I will try to remember, if it thinks a table column doesn't exist, I actually just might have missed declaring the projection for my `Cursor` correctly.

Comment: Yeah, the _id is the one easy to forget, as you don't explicitly use it in your code.